# Django REST Framework as backend for tracking user history

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to track user history using a DRF backend. For that, I've created a history table that will get a new timestamped row with each update. This model is a many-to-one and has a reference to the user model by a foreign key.

Here comes the confusing part. Every time I pull up the user profile, I would like to also pull the last entry into the history table. Thus, I am considering adding a couple of columns in the table which get updated with every insert into the history table since this is probably less expensive than performing a secondary lookup each time. I'd like some feedback on this approach.

Additionally, I'm slightly confused by how to perform this update/insert combination via a single API endpoint as DRF seems to only support one-to-one CRUD.

For illustrative purposes, I'd like to achieve the following via a single API view:

User hits API endpoint with access token and update values --> Insert history table --> update user table for user's row with inserted details

Thanks!

Comment: "Thus, I am considering adding a couple of columns in the table which get updated with every insert into the.." can you explain this part better? seems to derail a reader

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah I'm thinking of storing a copy of the data on the last row of the history table on the main user table so that I don't have to perform an additional lookup with each query of the user profile

Comment: ah gotcha....but why complicate things further? Are you having millions of requests? This will likely come down to personal preference. In any case let me answer the 2nd part of the question on how to do it via a single API call

Comment: The resources I found seem to all point to either fetching the entire history table and slicing the last entry in python or adding a nested query that filters the latest result. I guess it's a trade off between writes and reads. Is there a consensus ratio of select vs update where it makes more sense to cache the  results in the user table? Also, if you know some efficient way to select the last history row from potentially hundreds of thousands of records, do let me know